# Moving from dynamic disk allocation to direct space disk via storage pool in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server, storage-engine

Pardon me if I am not clear in asking the question since I have very less understanding from storage terms used or how it's used with Sql server.

Currently our storage team is testing to move disk storage allocation from dynamic disk to storage pools via direct spaces as what I understood from them.

From what I understand we currently are provided storage in a manner where can we create mount points for each lun provided. We use those luns/ mount points for SQl server like data drives log file drives and tempdb as per best practices.

Now what storage team is moving using direct spaces where they will replace dynamic disk with storage pool which will give us one entire pool of storage say data drive of 20 TB where we can place all data files rather than splitting separately as in mount points. Same holds true for log and temp db as well.

They want us to do storage performance testing as they believe this to be a performance booster for our storage issues. But I have a different opinion based on how SQL might work.

Can someone please share the experience or any knowledge on above implementation?

Storage is the regular storage spaces not spaces to direct

Comment: Do you mean "regular" Storage Spaces https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/overview or Storage Spaces Direct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-overview?

Comment: It's really going to depends on the disk type, number of disks, connection type, and potentially the number of columns if you have either a very small or very large number of disks. Assuming storage spaces (not direct) then you could see a perf improvement as dynamic disks aren't known to be performant (depending on how they are setup).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft- Its regular storage spaces as confirmed by them